# How to add 'add people to group' functionality via graph API or FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm looking for a way to add 'add people to group' functionality to a web app. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can not simply add people to a group. The user has to want to be added :) I wouldn't want any old application adding me to groups without my permission.

The best thing you can do is have your application send an invite to the user. As [stated in the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/), you would need something like this :

> Applications can invite users to a group by issuing a POST request to
>   `/GROUP_ID/members/USER_ID` with an app access_token.

The user will then receive a notification which will allow them to respond to the invite.

Comment: What is the meaning of "with an app access_token"? is my code right?   
`$page = "/XXXXXX/members/".$id;`
`$token=$facebook->getAccessToken();`
`$facebook->api($page, "POST", array("access_token"=>$token));`

Comment: @KingGoeks - Take a look at [the documentation for access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/). An application token is a token that you can use to perform requests on behalf of the application and not the user.

Comment: [This edge was deprecated on April 4th, 2018, and can no longer be used.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/group/members)